# Unable to pass string value to my html google map

Tags: javascript, android

From this link http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html#why

i have used JavaScriptInterface .In the above link the getLatitude() and getLongitude() functions are returning double value to the map but using the same concept when i try to return a string value to my own map that takes string value to achieve  some task, i am unable to receive  string value there..

this is  so weird bcz  i just want to pass string value instead of double, but this is not working...
her is my complete code  [JavaScriptInterface() is not working in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989811/javascriptinterface-is-not-working-in-android)
any suggestions would be very much appreciated...

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, actually i have converted ascii to string....

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just convert the string to a double and then pass it.

```
    String aString = "Blah";
    Double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(aString);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your interest,i tried it but no use..have any other idea ?